# What is the differences between tag and enum dispatch in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, tags

The `std::unique_lock` has a couple of constructors accepting a `xxx_lock_t`. These are empty structures:

```
struct adopt_lock_t {};
struct defer_lock_t {};
struct try_to_lock_t {};
```

And they are correspond to values as follows.

```
constexpr adopt_lock_t  adopt_lock {};
constexpr defer_lock_t  defer_lock {};
constexpr try_to_lock_t try_to_lock {};
```

Finally, here are `std::unique_lock`'s constructors.

```
unique_lock (mutex_type& m, adopt_lock_t tag);
unique_lock (mutex_type& m, defer_lock_t tag) noexcept;
unique_lock (mutex_type& m, try_to_lock_t tag);
```

My question is:

Why they use this kind of tags instead of an enum type?

I think by using an enum we don't need to declare constructors per each type of locking. I also agree that by implementing each type's constructor, it doesn't need to compare which lock type is give in the implementation.

What are the main reasons?

Comment: You wouldn't have to declare different constructors if you used an `enum`, but then your single constructor would have to do 3 different things depending on the value of the `enum` (using a `switch` or similar). This way the compiler does the work for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you used `enum`, you had to determine at runtime which mode to chose when locking, à la:

```
if(mode == lock::adopt_lock) {
   ...
} else if(mode == lock::defer_lock) {
   ...
}
else ...
```

With overloads, you move this distinction to compile-time.

Comment: *"you move this distinction to compile-time."* - Which means there's no time wasted by branching on what to do. The correct c'tor is just called. C++ and it's "don't pay what what you don't need" motto again.

Answer (score 2):

> I also agree that by implementing each type's constructor, it doesn't need to compare which lock type is give in the implementation

But do you understand what that means? The c'tor will only ever do one type of locking, with either approach. But If the branching is in the c'tor, everybody pays for it. Even those who know in advance what branch they'll take. C++ is all about not paying for overhead you don't require. Implementing it like this allows for the following:

1. If you know in advance how you'll be locking, you don't pay for any branching.
2. If you don't know in advance, you can easily branch yourself. It will require default constructing of the lock, and (move) assigning to it. But those two operations will be fairly cheap anyway. It won't be too much added cost to the branch itself.

Comment: You mean there is no significant difference on computation and space cost. It make people to pay attention to only small piece of code blocks they are interested in. Am I right?

Comment: @jwchoi - Pretty much. People will be able to get exactly what they require. Their code won't run slower because the c'tor will have to figure out how to do what they want. It will instead be a dedicated one, that does **exactly** what they want, and no more.